# How to design an "Invoke-WebRequest" for multiple API calls with more than one variable from CSV?

Tags: json, powershell, csv, darksky

I am trying to call Dark Sky API for weather forecast data for each location in a CSV file with hundreds lines and write them to a text file. Here's an example of the first 5 lines of the CSV...

```
ip              city        region_code zip     latitude  longitude
75.161.17.209   Albuquerque NM          87114   35.1868  -106.6652
68.55.28.227    Plymouth    MI          48170   42.3688  -83.4799
72.95.198.227   Homestead   PA          15120   40.3926  -79.9052
68.180.94.219   Normal      IL          61761   40.5124  -88.9883
75.132.165.245  Belleville  IL          62226   38.5352  -90.0006
```

The uri is formatted like this...

```
https://api.darksky.net/forecast/[APIKey]/$latitude ,$longitude ,$ForcastTime ?exclude=currently,minutely,hourly,flags&units=us
```

There are 3 variables in this uri. `$latitude`, `$longitude`, and `$ForecastTime`. `$ForecastTime` is easy, because it is the same for all requests, so I have that defined already as...

```
$ForecastTime = Get-Date -Date $(Get-Date).AddDays(1) -Format yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss
```

...in order to give me Tomorrow's forecast info. This is the format Dark Sky calls for and works just fine.

I'm having trouble defining `$latitude` and `$longitude` as variables and formatting the `Invoke-WebRequest` so I can pull the weather data for the entire string of locations.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: when you read in a CSV file via `Import-CSV` you get an array of objects. each object is one line from the CSV. each property of that object is named from the header line & contains the value i that column of that row. for instance, `$CVS_Import[0].latitude` of the 1st row in your demo data would be `35.1868`. so you can iterate over the imported data and address each desired column by it's property name. ///// try it! [*grin*] just import that CSV into a $Var and then explore the resulting array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some sample code with `Invoke-RestMethod` but you can also work with `Invoke-WebRequest`. I like using `Invoke-RestMethod` for interacting with APIs.. Try and let me know if it works or not.

```
$ForecastTime = Get-Date -Date $(Get-Date).AddDays(1) -Format yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss;
Import-CSV './input.csv' | ForEach-Object {
     $result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://api.darksky.net/forecast/$apiKey/$_.latitude,$_.longitude,$ForcastTime?exclude=currently,minutely,hourly,flags&units=us"
}
```

PS: If a CSV column name has spaces in it then you can read the column as `$_.'Region Code'`

Comment: This will overwrite the returned data in the variable `$result` on every iteration, so only the last will persist. To gather all data move `$result =` in front of `Import-Csv`

Comment: @LotPings Agreed. If the input CSV file is large, you don't want to keep results in memory but Export them as you retrieve it using Export-CSV or some other way within the loop. Any advise?.

Comment: Directly pipe `ForEach-Object{...} | Export-Csv ...`